# Is it possible to intercept a timeout method without AroundTimeout annotation?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jar, interceptor

My company is currently using an old javaee jar (5.2.0) which doesn't contain the AroundTimeOut class. The jar cannot be changed because it will occur some major impacts. My manager asks me to intercept a timeout method.. Do you know if there is a way to workaround this issue?

This is the method that I use:

```
@Timeout
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    @Interceptors(CorrelationIdInterceptor.class)
    public void handleTimeout(Timer timer) {
```

And the interceptor:

```
public class CorrelationIdInterceptor {


    private static final String CORRELATION_ID = "CORRELATION_ID";
    private static final String GET_CORRELATION_ID = "getCorrelationId";

    private static final Logger LOGGER = 
    Logger.getLogger(CorrelationIdInterceptor.class);


    @AroundInvoke
    public Object log(final InvocationContext ic) throws Exception {

        String webServiceMethodName = ic.getMethod().getName();


        if(webServiceMethodName.equalsIgnoreCase("handleTimeout")){
            webServiceMethodName="SIBOI"+":"+ webServiceMethodName;
        }
```

Comment: We couldn't help you without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including proper example input/output data.

Comment: What does "is using an old javaee jar" mean? As compile dependency? But at runtime EE6 is supported?

Comment: Yes for the compilation it is not supported. In fact, a work on a release branch and the jar which is used on it is the 5.2.0 without the AroundTimeout class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add in your ejb-jar.xml

```
    <assembly-descriptor>
      <interceptor-binding>
         <ejb-name>full.path.to.your.ejb</ejb-name>
         <interceptor-class>full.path.to.your.interceptor</interceptor-class>
         <method-name>method.in.your.ejb</method-name>
      </interceptor-binding>
   </assembly-descriptor>
```